# Is there a closed form expression for $f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+1}\frac{1}{i!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form

I have the series

$$
f(n) = \frac{1}{1!} - \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} - \frac{1}{4!} + ...... + \frac{1}{n!} \\
\text{or} \\
f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+1}\frac{1}{i!}
$$

Is there a closed form solution for this equation?

Comment: It is a partial sum of $1-1/e$.

Comment: Aside from RobPratt's answer, I doubt there's much more to be said. You can obtain a sort of closed form in terms of the incomplete and regular gamma functions (see [Wolfram's result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5En+%28-1%29%5E%7Bi%2B1%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bi%21%7D)), but that probably isn't quite what you want.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Ah I see. Yeah I was hoping for something that would allow me to compute the expression for any $n$ quickly by hand.

Answer (score 4):

A *derangement* is a permutation with no fixed point, i.e. a permutation where no element is in its original position. Let $d(n)$ be the number of derangements of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. There's a nice combinatorial argument that shows
$$
d(n)= n!\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}
$$Note that in terms of your function, we have
$$
f(n) = 1- \frac{d(n)}{n!}
$$
Then you can use the Taylor series for $e^{-x}$ to compute
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{d(n)}{n!} = e^{-1}
$$Since the sum is alternating and converges quickly, we have
$$
f(n) = \begin{cases}
1- \frac{1}{n!} \lfloor n!/e\rfloor,& n \text{ odd}\\
1- \frac{1}{n!} \lceil n!/e\rceil,& n \text{ even}\\
\end{cases}
$$I can't say how efficient this is, as it requires calculating $n!$, computing the floor/ceiling quotient somewhat accurately, and then dividing by $n!$ again. But it's something.